# View don't appear the second time [Swift]

Tags: swift, uikit

In my swift app I've create these two functions:

```
func presentAlertView() {

    backgroundLogOutView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    backgroundLogOutView.backgroundColor = currentTheme.backgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    logOutAlertView.frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
    logOutAlertView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width / 2, y: view.frame.height / 2 - (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height)!)

    view.addSubview(backgroundLogOutView)
    backgroundLogOutView.addSubview(logOutAlertView)

    logOutAlertView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    logOutAlertView.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {

        self.logOutAlertView.alpha = 1
        self.logOutAlertView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    })
}

@objc func removeAlertView() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {

        self.logOutAlertView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.logOutAlertView.alpha = 0

        self.backgroundLogOutView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.backgroundLogOutView.alpha = 0

    }) {(success: Bool) in

        self.logOutAlertView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.backgroundLogOutView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.tableView.deselectRow(at: [0,4], animated: true)
    }
}
```

By tapping a button the function presentAlertView() is invoked and the views appear then when the function removeAlertView() is invoked the views disapeear. And here all ok.
But when I tapped the button the second time the views don't appear!
Why this happened?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
self.backgroundLogOutView.alpha = 0
```

is present in `removeAlertView()`.

```
self.backgroundLogOutView.alpha = 1
```

may be missing in `presentAlertView()`.